# ERROR history.push is not a function TypeError: history.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

when I try to use `history.push("/")`; I am given the following error:

> ERROR history.push is not a function TypeError: history.push is not a
> function.

I am sure that I have imported it correctly from `react-router-dom` but I am not sure why its not working. I am using `"react-router-dom": "^5.3.4"` for my project. Any help / suggestions will be much appreciated, I have included my code in the following, Thank you.

```
import { Avatar, Box, Button, Menu, MenuButton, MenuDivider, MenuItem, MenuList, Text, Tooltip } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { BellIcon, ChevronDownIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons';
import { color } from 'framer-motion';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ChatState } from '../../Context/ChatProvider';
import ProfileModal from './ProfileModal';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const SideDrawer = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [loadingChat, setLoadingChat] = useState();

  const { user } = ChatState();

  const  history = useHistory();

  const logoutHandler = () => {
      localStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
      history.push("/");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Box display={"flex"}
           justifyContent={"space-between"}
           alignItems={"center"}
           width={"100%"}
           p={"5px 10px 5px 10px"}
           borderWidth={"5px"}
           bg={'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'}
           borderColor={"#107869"}
           >
        <Tooltip 
        label = "Search For Users" 
        hasArrow 
        placement='bottom-end'
        >
          <Button variant={'ghost'} color={"#e02929"}>
            {/* <i className="fa-light fa-magnifying-glass" style={{ color: '#0e490f' }}></i> */}
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            <Text display={{base: 'none', md: "flex"}} px={"4"}>
              Search
            </Text>
          </Button>
        </Tooltip>

        <Text fontSize={"4xl"}
              fontFamily={"Work sans"}
              color={"white"}
              >
          Hatchat
        </Text>

        <div>
          <Menu>
            <MenuButton p={1}>
              <BellIcon fontSize={"2xl"} m={1} />
            </MenuButton>
            {/* <MenuList></MenuList> */}
          </Menu>

          <Menu>
            <MenuButton as={Button} 
                        rightIcon={<ChevronDownIcon />}
                        >
              <Avatar size={"sm"} 
                      cursor={"pointer"}
                      name={user.name}
                      src={user.pic} 
                      />
            </MenuButton>
            <MenuList>
              <ProfileModal user={user}>
                  {/* <MenuItem color={"#107869"}> My Profile </MenuItem> */}
              </ProfileModal>
              <MenuDivider/>
              <MenuItem color={"#107869"} onClick={logoutHandler}> Logout </MenuItem>
            </MenuList>
          </Menu>
        </div>
      </Box>
    </div>
  )
};

export default SideDrawer;
```

Comment: I don't see evidence of any other `react-router-dom` components/code in the post. Are you rendering this `SideDrawer` component within a routing context provided by a router? Can you [edit] to provide a more complete [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
const history = useHistory()
```

to

```
import createBrowserHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory"

export const history = createBrowserHistory({
    forceRefresh: true
})
```